# Magento 2 PWA overwrite Gallery component

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.5, pwa, component

I am able to overwrite modify the following components:

Main, App, Footer, Header, Logo, Routes, CategoryTree by following Doc: ref:https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/pwa-studio-fundamentals/modify-site-footer/

To modify component such as CategoryTree i required override Webpack plugin.
REF:https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-create-pwa-storefront-using-magento-2-pwa-studio/

But not able to figure it out how to modify/overwrite Gallery component.

anyone any ideas what I' missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about Gallery component used in category and search pages.

In this case you're missing some other components override in the chain. For example if you're trying to override Gallery component in category page you should also override categoryContent.js root template since it includes Gallery component via relative path inclusion https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/develop/packages/venia-ui/lib/RootComponents/Category/categoryContent.js#L11

Comment: Yes Thank you. I figured that out just before your answered it. Do you know how to overwrite RootComponents ? as at the moment I have updated this file inside nodes_module path in my custom project to point Galerry to my custom project folder Gallery component. Shouldn't this be overwritten in **custom-project/src/RootComponents** ? I have done so but I didn't seem to work.

Comment: Ooh my bad I have to recompile and and run `yarn run watch` is working now!

Comment: Hi @JulianoVargas, did you found a way to overriding RootComponents?